# How to make a COM DLL?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Just another of those things that I have never done before but which is probably simple ... when you know how

I am using VB Express 2008 and need to create a very simple DLL.

I already built and tested it and now I find that it has to be a COM DLL. How do I go about that?

---

Edit: in reply to @Kman -  I looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx

and changed my code to

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace My_DLL

  <ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)> _
  Public Class My_DLL

      <ComVisible(True)> Public Sub Function_A()
      End Sub

      <ComVisible(True)> Public Sub Function_B()
      End Sub
  End Class
End Namespace
```

but I still don't the functions using DLL Explorer, whereas I do see them in the old DLL ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/nettocom.aspx

Maybe
http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/vb.net-2005/creating-and-managing-components-in-vb.net-2005-section-1.html

The MS pages about it are here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3x7357ez%28vs.71%29.aspx

Follow the suggestions and if you want to learn more check out the following book
.NET and Com the Complete Interoperability Guide. Everything is explained there in whatever detail you like.

Comment: wow, that was quick (+1).  I already found the first one, and am working my way through it. IF necessary, I will also check out the others & get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Qualify your dll for interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439.aspx); mark its [ComVisibleAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx) to true.

Right click your project, goto Build tab, and check the last Checkbox, which says "register for COM interop".

Comment: +1 Thanks for replying. 
I don't see "register for COM interop" in VB Express 2008 ... but in Project/Properties/Application/Assembly Information I do see Make assembly COM-visible ... that seems to make no difference

Comment: Please see **Walkthrough: Creating COM Objects with Visual Basic .NET** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x66s8zcd(VS.71).aspx